# generate Numbers without loops

Tags: arrays, recursion, indexing, methods, numbers

Implement a static-public method named `generateNumbers` in the class `Functionality.java`.
The method gets two integer values as input parameters and returns an integer array.
Signature: `generateNumbers(int start, int end) : int[]`

The method generateNumbers shall fill an array recursively (!) with the integer values from the start index "start" to the end index "end".start index and end index are included and shall be enclosed.the filled array is returned afterwards.if the start index is really greater than the end index, an empty array shall be returned.the method shall work for negative input values as well.
Example: `generateNumbers(-2,1)` ---> [-2, -1, 0, 1].

Note: The creation of help methods is allowed and simplifies recursive implementation.
But the auxiliary methods must be called by the required method `generateNumbers`.

I should not solve the problem iteratively and do not use loops! The use of external libraries or other content is also prohibited. Well I have no Idea how to go further with my code

My code

```
public static int[] generateNumbers(int start, int end) {
    if(start == end){
        return numbers[start];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What does the numbers array contain? Where and how are you declaring it? Provide full code for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand in your explanation, this seems to be what you are asking.

```
        public static int[] generateNumbers(int start, int end) {
            if (start > end) {
                return null;
            }
            int[] numbers = new int[end - start + 1];
            generateNumbersHelper(numbers, 0, start, end);
            return numbers;
        }

        public static void generateNumbersHelper(int[] numbers, int index, int start, int end) {
            if (start > end) return;
            numbers[index] = start;
            generateNumbersHelper(numbers, index + 1, start + 1, end);
        }
```

You simply have to keep calling the recursive function with new index and new start value until start exceeds the end and then you can return.

Comment: For Example: generateNumbers(-2,1) it should return ---> [-2, -1, 0, 1].

Comment: Sorry my bad. I put the initial if condition wrongly. It should be working now.

Comment: Thanks for your Help